# Powershell param: accept either username and password or a credential object

Tags: security, powershell, credentials

I have a script which reads statistics from a vCenter server. To connect to vCenter, I issue the Connect-VIServer cmdlet from within my script. This cmdlet accepts either -User and -Password or -Credential.
The Connect-VIServer cmdlet also allows the -SaveCredentials parameter.

Now I would like to have the exact same behavior in my script, accept -User & -Password OR a PSCredential object. If none of them are specified, prompt for the username and password. And with -SaveCredentials specified, save the specified credentials in the local credential store.

Any idea or code snippet really appreciated!

Cheers, Ernst

Comment: What have you done so far? do you have any code and needs help or you expect us to write it for you?

Answer (score 1):

off the top of my head you could maybe do...

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
[string]$user,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)]
[string]$pass,

[parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
[credential]$creds
)
```

Then do a check on each parameter and decide which, if any to use, or prompt for some creds with a save option